# Пожертвовал собой ради/за

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика, предлоги

Как правильно написать: "**пожертвовал собой за...**" или "**пожертвовал собой ради...**"?
Или возможны оба варианта в разных контекстах?

Answer (score 1):

Безупречно второе ("ради").  Предлог "за" характерен для близкого по смыслу выражении "отдал жизнь за (царя, родину)", поскольку в нём формально присутствует "обмен" (одно отдаётся "за" другое). "Пожертвовал собой за" *возможно* в специфическом контексте, напр. в религиозных текстах встречается фраза: "Он пожертвовал собой за грехи наши..." (здесь смысл далёк и от того, который придаёт выражению "ради", и от того, где просматривается "обмен" - здесь нечто близкое к "наказанию за...", принятому на себя вместо кого-то).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, скорее всего, (1) пожертвовать собой ради  других или (2) отдать жизнь за других.

"Пожертвовать собой за других" может содержать неясную семантику (например, вместо других, которые должны были пожертвовать).

**ПОЖЕРТВОВАТЬ** 2. кем-чем. Добровольно отказаться от чего-л. в пользу кого-, чего-л.; поступиться, пренебречь чем-л. П. всем своим имуществом. П. собственным благополучием. П. жизнью. П. всем во имя кого-л. **П. собой (отдать жизнь за кого-, что-л.).**

В то же время в примерах можно встретить оба варианта:

(2) У женщины несчастье: несколько лет назад погиб любимый человек ― полярный летчик, ― спасая пропавшую экспедицию, **пожертвовал собой ради** других. [Карен Шахназаров. Курьер (1986)]

(1) Само шествие крестного хода в собор также знаменовало обретение горнего Сиона ― Иерусалима, то есть рая для тех, кто **пожертвовал собой за** общенародное дело. [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по русскому искусству (2000)]